# Dynamic library link failed Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, dynamic

I built C++ applications to Linux dynamic libraries, each dynamic library is also depending and linking to other dynamic libraries,it was fine to built all dynamic libraries, but when I built an executable application to link all application dynamic libraries, it failed one library to link another library:

g++ -pthread -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -Wl,-z,relro -lc  -o wifi_scan WiFiScan.o  -lmnl -lglib-2.0 -ldbus-1 -ldbus-glib-1 -lgobject-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lboost_program_options -lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lboost_date_time -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -lmsgpackc -lLogger -lApplication -lNetwork -lUtility

libApplication.so: undefined reference to Logger::Log::SystemLog(...)

But that Logger::Log::SystemLog(...) is in library link -lLogger, what I could be missing here?

Thank you.

Kind regards.

Comment: Try adding `-lLogger` once more at the end.

Comment: Better to use `CMake` build system. Unless you are doing the exercise.

Comment: The relative order of `-l` parameters is important! Loosely speaking, linker reads them from left to right, and if by the time `-lLib` is encountered, no previous code needed that library, it will be forgotten. So, if `Application` uses something from `Logger`, you'll get an undefined reference. Check the order of libraries. If you have a circular dependency, repeat some libraries once again or use `-Wl,--start-group`/`-Wl,--end-group`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tomo Ceferin and all responses, put the -lLogger at the end did the trick.

Greatly appreciated